# Findle Loot-A-Rang Legion version

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any other items or abilities similar to Loot-A-Rang with less restriction?

The old non-toy version of Findle Loot-A-Rang used to be able to loot pretty much anywhere even inside dungeons and other places that might not seem useful at first.

My biggest reason to use Findle loot-a-rang is because sometime a rather large corpse would fall on top of a tiny corpse. The large corpse is unlootable because either it has no loot or was killed by someone else. However the small corpse is and you can see the "shining twinkle" that shows you have loot. So I use findle loot-a-rang to grab it and move on quicker.

However with Legion launch Blizzard for some reason or other decide to restrict all items, that I know of, like this to either having 125 engineering (not possible if you want to be a miner/JC or tailor/enchanter as an example) or using it in Draenor out-world contents.

Hunter's fetch doesn't count here because it is still restricted to hunter. It also has an additional drawback of pulling mobs.

So as a result it is noticeable just a tiny longer to loot as a non-engineer or non-hunter.

Is there a good workaround?

Comment: You do know they implemented multiple corpse looting like 3 years ago right? That means all you have to do is loot something near this corpse and It also will be looted

Comment: Are you really suggesting that I waste time finding a second mob to kill to loot it? What if it is an elite? Wait for the bigger obstructing body to despawn? They all take longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now there is **no alternative** to the two you have mentioned.

Sadly, you need to be hunter (Glyph of fetch) or Engineer (non-toy Loot-a-Rang).

I know how it feels to kill mobs in obstructed areas where no other mobs are nearby or they're too many/deadly (Suramar....) or the corpses despawn too fast (Broken Shore).

You can only try to kill something else nearby or take the risk and wait for the big guy to despawn in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Like DLY said there is no other solution with items to my knowledge.

I have bound the interact function to a hotkey and use a /tar macro to loot small corpses under bigger ones without loot. (only works if you know the name of the lootable corpse)

/tar corpse -> push interact -> get loot